# strange macro construstion

Tags: c, macros

I found this macro in c source which I'm porting now:

```
#define Round256(p0, p1) \
X##p0 += X##p1;
```

There is no variable **X** in that code. Can anyone tell me what the symbol **#** do in this context?

Comment: What a stupid macro and what a stupid name for it.  Please get rid of it in your ported code and just use the right `+=` statement in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`##` is the pasting operator. It contatenates X (literally) and each value. So `Round256(one, two)` will be converted to `Xone += Xtwo`, for example.

Answer (score 3):

`##` textually appends two strings together.

So in your example, if called as follows:

```
Round256(one, two)
```

will be translated to:

```
Xone += Xtwo;
```

Answer (score 2):

The macro simply stringizes the values

Suppose it was called like this

```
Round256(1,2)
```

It would be expanded by the preprocessor as

```
X1 += X2
```

Which seems to resemble variable X1...n somewhere....

The `##` concatenates the stringized values together.

The reason I used numerical values is in the name of the macro itself.